# "insmod: ERROR: Could not insert module xxx.ko: Operation not permitted"

Tags: kernel, rootkit, chkrootkit

I try to install a rootkit to test chkrootkit, so I tried many rootkits from github and after I do make, I try insmod xxx.ko, but it dispalys this error:
"insmod: ERROR: Could not insert module xxx.ko: Operation not permitted"
Can someone please help me to resolve this problem?

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu?

Comment: yes, I'm using ubuntu 20.04.1

Comment: Are you using `sudo` with `insmod`?

Comment: yes I used sudo insmod xxx.ko

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: Thank you, I'm new on ubuntu, how to do this please?

Comment: It is actually part of your BIOS for the computer you are using. Go into the BIOS during boot and disable it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get "Required key not available" when install 3rd party kernel modules or after a kernel upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-3rd-party-kernel-modules)